# How to periodically update ElasticSearch index? UPDATE or REBUILD?

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose there are **fixed** 1 million titles of articles to be indexed, and each article has two **growing** fields with `"type": "rank_feature"`: `view_count` and `favor_count`. I have to update the value of counters every hours in order to boosting hot articles in search result.

Since the UPDATE operation in ES and Lucene is equivalent to search-delete-create, I wonder what is the proper solution in my case. Does UPDATE operation save unnecessary ANALYZE steps for those fixed titles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update does not make your analysis more efficient — it still has to process the entire document again.

If you have 2 fields that change frequently and other fields that are more static, I'd restructure the documents to use [parent/child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html):

- The parent contains the static fields
- The child has your 2 frequently changing fields

That way you can avoid the (re) analysis of documents as much as possible. This comes at the cost of some overhead at search-time, but should be manageable if you only have a single child.